# Rails: How can I convert bootstrap template with rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I downloaded bootstrap theme files, it includes the static HTML, CSS and js files. If I'm using the same bootstrap theme in rails app, how can I integrate those files with rails application

Comment: That is a broad question. Did you have a look at the [Rails Guide about Assets](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)? What exactly is unclear or not working?

Comment: All the explanations are unclear, How can I load the paticular css and js files. In HTML files, they are used JS files in the body section. How can I do that same?

Comment: Did you try to `require` the bootstrap CSS and JS files in the applications JS in `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` and CSS in `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css` (or whatver file that is included in the layout ? or try including them directly in your layout using `javascript_include_tag` or `stylesheet_link_tag`

Comment: Is this your first ruby-on-rails application? Have you used it before? Or did you use sprockets before and are you now switching to webpacker?

Comment: This is my first rails application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Broadly/simply:

When using the rails 4-5 asset pipeline:

- copy the `js` files to `app\assets\javascript` and require in `application.js`
- copy the `css` files to `app/assets/stylesheets` and require in `application.css`

The `index.html` page (or in general, the static html pages) will have to be split-up into

- a "layout", e.g. `app/view/layouts/application.html.erb` (or use your preferred templating framework, I prefer `haml/slim`) and edit it to keep header/footer elements only (aka the repeating elements for all pages, or a set of pages)
- copy the remainder (the contents) to the main `index.html.erb` of the controller where you want to copy/use the template

Comment: Hey @nathanvda All the problems were solved. Now it's working fine for me